# Mongoose populate followers same document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to populate ObjectId parameters from the same Schema of users What am trying to do is I have 'Users' document and each record has followers and the ref is the same schema of users.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {type: String, unique: true, trim: true},
  password: {type: String},
  email: {type: String, trim: true},
  avatar: {type: String},
  fullname: {type: String},
  bio: {type: String},
  phone: {type: Number},
  country: {type: String},
  postal: {type: Number},
  followers: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  followed: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  registered: {type: Date, default: Date.now}

});

var User = mongoose.model('users',userSchema);
```

Now when I tried to print the user information followers array return with ObjectId not the whole information

I try to print with this snippet

```
User.find().exec(function(error, groups) {    
    return res.status(200).send(groups);
  });
```

Comment: Please show your code where you try to retrieve the user's infos

Comment: @t3__rry Added in my question

Comment: As @Kxng Kombian suggested you could make use of Mongoose's `population` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population
But in your definition you need `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

Comment: Still get [ { followers: [ 5a8c52a9a11412b04b48a933 ], the object id instead of object information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve here is

```
User.find({})
.populate('followers')
.populate('followed')
.then(users => {

})
```

This will populate with both the followers and followed with their respective user objects

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

Comment: add `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` before your mongodb connection

Comment: It is working fine, the problem was Ref is incorrect I changed Ref: User to Ref: users